# the package path must not be started with "java " in the configuration of Action

Tags: java, struts2, web

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="loginAction" class="java.LoginAction">
        <result name="input">/login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

If I configure the location with the package path starting with `java.*` it will lead the error.
The stack is

```
Caused by: Action class [java.LoginAction] not found.
```

Can anybody tell me the reason?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be putting your own classes into a package structure beginning with `java.*` to start with. I believe there are at least some security managers which prevent this, and it would be a very bad idea in general anyway: classes in `java.*` packages are expected to be part of the JRE, not user-created.

The error you're getting suggests that possibly the class loader being used is refusing to load clases in packages beginning with `java.` which is another manifestation of the same thing, basically.

Why would you *want* to put your class in a package called `java`? (I'm assuming you have actually tried to do so. If you just *randomly* decided to specify the package name as `java` without actually having a class which declares that package, then *of course* it will fail.)

Just as an example, I tried running this program:

```
package java;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Woot");
    }
}
```

The result was this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name:
 java
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: java.Test.  Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 1):

The package (portion before the `.` in `java.LoginAction`) must match the `package` declaration of your `LoginAction` class. Look at the top of the file `LoginAction.java` for a line that starts with `package`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the package name `java` Struts2 is trying to load the `LoginAction` class from `java` package of default JRE